# Performance degrades when compiling with _win32_winnt=0x0501 instead of 0x400

Tags: performance, winapi

Is anyone aware of any performance implications from changing the _win32_winnt from 0x400 to 0x0501?

I am compiling C++ on VS2005.
My Application is very communications oriented, doing quite a lot of Winsock work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm unaware of any particular performance-related issues, but if you could provide more specific details about how your performance is suffering, someone might be able to help.

For example, is your network throughput lower than you think it used to be?

Answer (score 1):

A value of 0x0400 targets _WIN32_WINNT_NT4, which is a smaller subset of the windows SDk that targets Windows 2000. That means you are excluding, ignoring and throwing away a lot of code that would have been compiled into your executable. So yes it will execute faster.

So when you define 0x0501 you are saying, yes give me all that rich extra goodness that the header files for Windows XP. However your application most likely will not run on windows 2000 due to failed imports. Since you are bringing in all that extra fatness, your compile times will be slower, and your code will be bigger, your executable will be bigger, and most likely it will be slower.

You can find more information here on these topics:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2007/04/11/2079137.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383745.aspx